# Why must an edit include at least 6 characters?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I just can't understand why this rule exists. We edit, because we want to improve the questions or answers. Sometimes, there is just a simple punctuation error or a typo. It could be just 1 or 2 characters. But the websites requires at least 6 characters for an edit. This is not reasonable!

Here is an example at https://askubuntu.com/questions/77149/how-to-find-text-and-replace-that-line-if-exists-with-terminal-otherwise-just-ap

> [image]

It's clear that *sur* is a typo. But I can't fix it!

[image]

Please consider lifting this restriction.

Comment: And in that ask ubunbtu case: just leave it for a 2K-er to fix. You don't want to mess with workarounds if your edit needs to go through a review queue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> if you don't mind how many digits your number has.
>
> If you are sur you want not more than 3 digits, you need extended (modern) regular expression rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's). You then need to provide the "-E" parameter

Let's see...

- The "i" in the initial "if" is not capitalised
- As you noted "sur" is a typo for "sure"
- "you want not more than 3 digits" is better written as "you want a maximum of 3 digits"
- "regular expression" should be "regular expression**s**"
- "extend (modern) regular expressions" should be "extend**ed** (modern) regular expressions"
- `-E` should be formatted as code

So there's far more than one letter to correct if you do this properly. There's almost never only one character to correct and if there was we don't want a committee of 3-5 people having to validate a one letter correction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree with you. But I'm not a native English speaker and I need to read really carefully to catch all these:-) In fact, I skimmed that answer really quickly and I only found that one...

Comment: We don't want you to skim really quickly.

Comment: And colons should be used before block quotations.

Comment: There are cases we want to correct only just a couple letters:  For example, a typo equation x + y = z which should be read as x + y = k.    It's only one letter change, but very significant.

Comment: @RobinHsu that's the sort of thing you [shouldn't correct at all](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) because it's not spelling or grammar. You'd be changing the meaning of the answer or maybe fixing the whole point of the question. If it's a wrong answer, write your own correct answer instead.